# When is the requestId equal to the loaderId in the Chrome DevTools Protocol?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I have a bunch of captured network requests originating from Google Chrome. The requests were captured with [the `requestWillBeSent` callback](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-requestWillBeSent), which has the following parameters:

```
requestId: RequestId
Request identifier.

loaderId: LoaderId
Loader identifier. Empty string if the request is fetched from worker.
```

Now, for most of these requests, the requestId is formatted like `25799.49`, and the loaderId like `8404BB9497057A198BC72AC5FFBF635B`.

But some requests have requestIds that are equal to the loaderId.

I wonder why this is the case, and what this signifies. For instance, look at these request and loader IDs:

```
 ["25799.13", "07F0091D2CD34936025433DF76F5C4E1"],
 ["25799.12", "07F0091D2CD34936025433DF76F5C4E1"],
 ["25799.11", "07F0091D2CD34936025433DF76F5C4E1"],
 ["25799.10", "07F0091D2CD34936025433DF76F5C4E1"],
 ["25799.5", "07F0091D2CD34936025433DF76F5C4E1"],
 ["25799.3", "07F0091D2CD34936025433DF76F5C4E1"],
 ["25799.4", "07F0091D2CD34936025433DF76F5C4E1"],
 ["25799.2", "07F0091D2CD34936025433DF76F5C4E1"],
 ["07F0091D2CD34936025433DF76F5C4E1", "07F0091D2CD34936025433DF76F5C4E1"],
 ["25654.40", "1798A5235B193303395CA1B011110B14"],
 ["25654.39", "1798A5235B193303395CA1B011110B14"],
 ["25654.38", "1798A5235B193303395CA1B011110B14"],
 ["25654.37", "1798A5235B193303395CA1B011110B14"],
 ["25654.36", "1798A5235B193303395CA1B011110B14"],
 ["25654.35", "1798A5235B193303395CA1B011110B14"],
 ["25654.34", "1798A5235B193303395CA1B011110B14"],
```

What does it mean when the two entries are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not read the Chromium source code, it would probably help here, but what I *have* read is the [playwright source code](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright). You can see on [this line](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/8b5e55d432a50a05605eaa6a988d74eb7e698901/packages/playwright-core/src/server/chromium/crNetworkManager.ts#L259) that matching loader and request IDs is one of the conditions for the request to be a navigation request:

```
const isNavigationRequest = requestWillBeSentEvent.requestId === requestWillBeSentEvent.loaderId && requestWillBeSentEvent.type === 'Document';
```

I'm not sure what requestId and loaderId matching but type != 'Document' means, though.